# Is it correct and natural to say "the cell phone plan comes with roaming mobile data"?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *the cell phone plan come with roaming mobile data* mean you can use it access the internet without additional charges abroad? For example:

> If you are going to travel abroad, I would go with this plan as it comes with **roaming mobile data**.

If it doesn't sound particularly natural, would you tell me how you would phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

The only change I would make is to use "comes" instead of "come". The subject of your sentence is the plan and that is singular.